# How to record specific window on OBS

Tags: obs-studio

I know how to capture the desktop, but that shows everything including OBS itself. How do I record a specific window on it's own? (i.e. Minecraft Bedrock Edition)

I am on Windows 10, and have the newest version of OBS.

Answer (score 1):

In the OBS add sources menu, you can select to add a "Window Capture" or "Game Capture". Each of them serve the same relative purpose but Game Capture has some optimizations within it to make it run/capture/broadcast better. [[source]](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/monitor-capture-vs-game-capture-or-window-capture.48140/) [[guide for Game Capture]](http://electrostingz.com/how-to-configure-obs-for-game-capture/) Note that if you are dealing with a windowed game or anything else that isn't a game, you should use Window Capture.

HTH!